# Wordpress: push new plugin version

Tags: wordpress

I have a silly issue updating a Wordpress plugin I made : https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-youtube-videos-as-wp-post/

I'm tired and I can't figure out why the plugin repo is still saying: Download version 1.4, when I updated it to 1.5.

I changed the stable tag in the readme.txt in the trunk and the 1.5 tag folder: https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/import-youtube-videos-as-wp-post/trunk/readme.txt

```
=== Plugin Name ===
Contributors: enguerranws
Donate link: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=BQNTS4S2PEQVN
Tags: youtube, content, videos, enguerranws, google api, youtube api, youtube importer, video importer
Requires at least: 3.0.1
Tested up to: 4.7.3
Stable tag: 1.5
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
```

What do I miss there?

Comment: could you be missing the file header in your plugin? https://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main file version is 1.4

```
/*
  Plugin Name: Import YouTube videos as WP Posts
  Plugin URI: http://www.enguerranweiss.fr
  Description: Get a video list from a request to Youtube (free query, playlist ID, channel ID) and add their content to your own Wordpress :)
  Version: 1.4
  Author: Enguerran Weiss
  Author URI: http://www.enguerranweiss.fr
 */
```

Try to change the version and Upload.

Comment: I feel really stupid, but you're right. Thanks and sorry :/